# Using ufw to block telnet from specified host

Tags: networking, firewall, telnet, ufw

I'm new to `ufw` tool, I'm trying to block a specified host from requesting `telnet` while allowing other hosts on the network to do so.

When I use this command:

```
sudo ufw deny 23
```

The other host is unable to `telnet` to me. However, this denies everything that uses port 23 and all other hosts who attempt using `telnet`.

Therefore, I have tried the following:

```
sudo ufw deny from HOST port 23
sudo ufw deny to HOST port 23
```

I was hoping this will deny that host but it literally did nothing. The other host is still able to `telnet` as if the rules do not exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May I know why I'm being downvoted? Is the question not meeting some standard? Or just some guy who decided the question is too easy for him that it doesn't qualify to be asked? I said I'm new and I needed help. Thanks for discouraging people to ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ufw deny from IP to any port 23`

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful as I had a confusion when I viewed the status.

Comment: can you give more of an explanation as to what "to any port" is doing?

Comment: "to any port 23" -> allow access to any target IP on port 23

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify your local IP (e.g. `local_ip`) as well as you romote IP (e.g. `remote_ip`) you want to block

```
sudo ufw deny in from `local_ip` to `remote_ip` port 23
```